# How to remove or edit "Grand Total to be Charged" in order email in magento 2

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2.2, order-email

As I mentioned in the headline I need to alter the **Grand Total to be Charged** section in the order email. My store is running in **LKR** as Base currency and **AUD** as another currency.

If I place an order in AUD, I am getting the order email like below. Which is showing the  **Grand Total to be Charged** in LKR.

[image]

I used an override the **Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals.php** like below.

My **di.xml** file is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="Ayakil\AudDevelopment\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals"/>
</config>
```

My Totals.php in the ( **Ayakil\AudDevelopment\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Order** ) is like below.

```
protected function _initTotals()
{
if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
        $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
                'label' => __('My custom text'), // changed
                'is_formated' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And tried to remove the **base_grandtotal** too like this. I am getting the email like below after this modification.

[image]

```
$this->removeTotal('base_grandtotal');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_initTotals` is protected method, you can't use plugin for that.

So there are 2 ways to do this:

1. Overwrite the class, so you can do whatever you want.
2. The better way is to add your own initTotal.

Here I explain the second way, as you can see in the Block, initTotals is invoked from beforeHtml

[image]

According to the logic, if a child has its own initTotals function, it will be invoked.

So you can write your own class, which will have a initTotals method and then do something like `$this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = your custom`

You can search for magento code to see example about it, for ex this class has initTotals function of its own
`\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Totals`

Comment: thank you for your answer, In my code I am trying to overwrite it right?

Comment: Your code uses plugin which is not correct, because plugin cannot work with protected methods.

Comment: I am not using a plugin here, I just override the totals.php, please explain

Comment: My bad, just check your code, it's overwritten.

Did you post the full code or just a part of it? If it's a full code then you should rewrite your code. You need to have pretty much the same code as the old class and then make changes in your code. (copy the whole initTotals function and then change what needed in your code)

Comment: thank you, I copied entire inittotals method to my overtite totals.php and changed it, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the "Grand Total To Be Charged" line by changing **vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\totals.phtml**. You can achieve this by:

1. First, [create a simple Magento 2 theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).
2. Then, copy **vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\totals.phtml** to **<your_theme_directory>\Magento_Sales\templates\order\totals.phtml**
3. At the opening php tag (line 10) add the following like of code `$block->removeTotal('base_grandtotal');`.

You're **totals.phtml** file should then look something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 */

/* Remove 'Grand Total to be Charged' block from totals */
$block->removeTotal('base_grandtotal');

?>
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()) : ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false) ?>
    <?php else :?>
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used to copy the entire **_initTotals()** method from the original file and paste it to overwrite the file and did the changes to `base_grandtotal` like below.

```
/**
     * Base grandtotal
     */
    if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
        $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($source->getGrandTotal()),
                'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                'is_formated' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
```

This worked for me, I added

`'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($source->getGrandTotal()),`

instead of

`'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),`